# Get adjacent pairs of elements from vector via iterator in c++

Tags: c++

I want to iterate over all adjacent pairs elements in a vector. For example, if I have a vector `{1, 2, 3, 4}`, I want my iterator to return the following:

```
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
```

I know how to iterate over one element at a time using the following:

```cpp
vector<int> numbers == {1, 2, 3, 4};
for (vector<int>::const_iterator it = numbers.cbegin(); 
     words != numbers.cend(); 
     ++it) 
{
    cout << *it << endl;
}
```

But I don't know how to get the next element as well.

Comment: Get the *next* element using [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next)! You need your loop to stop one element earlier though.

Comment: Is there a good reason for which you're punishing yourself and the future code maintainer using iterators instead of an index?

Comment: Or just `*(it+1)`, but std::next is more generic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector::iterator` can be used almost like a pointer.

Make sure the conditional of the loop is altered and use `*(it+1)` in the loop.

```
vector<int> numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4}; // One =, not two.

// If the vector is empty, skip the block.
if ( !numbers.empty() )
{
   vector<int>::const_iterator end = numbers.cend() - 1;

   for (vector<int>::const_iterator it = numbers.cbegin(); it != end; ++it) {
      cout << '(' << *it << ',' << *(it+1) << ')' << endl;
   }
}
```

[Working demo](https://ideone.com/LVGTyk).

Comment: @6502 that is not an issue. See `end = numbers.cend() - 1`

Comment: @6502, that won't happen because the conditional makes sure of that.

Comment: This is a great answer! Why dereference the iterator instead of using `it[1]` as in @wilx's answer?

Comment: @goatboy3million, even though the standard says that `it[1]` is translated as `*(it+1)`, I prefer to use the first for only with arrays.

Comment: This gives undefined behaviour if `it` is one before the end  (or if the vector is empty).

Comment: @Peter, no, it does not. See the [working demo](https://ideone.com/LVGTyk).

Answer (score 3):

Vector's iterator is [random access iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator). You can use `operator[]` on the iterator to get next element like this: `it[1]`

Comment: @Peter But that's obvious, isn't it?

Comment: One thing I've learned on this site, is that when someone leaves something unsaid because they consider it "obvious",  it is almost certainly not obvious to someone else.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (auto it = numbers.cbegin(); it != numbers.end() && std::next(it) != numbers.end(); ++it)
{
    cout << *it << " " << *std::next(it) << endl;

    // or, abusing C++17
    auto&& [first, second] = std::tie(*it, *std::next(it));
    cout << first << " " << second << endl;
}
```

If you really want an iterator that will yield the pair, I've hastily put together one for a proof of concept. Beware it's not extensively tested.

Usage:

```
for (auto&& [first, second] : AdjacentRange{numbers})
{
    cout << first << " " << second << endl;
}

// or

for (auto&& pair : AdjacentRange{numbers})
{
    cout << pair.first << " " << pair.second << endl;
}
```

Implementation:

```
template <class It>
struct AdjancetRangeIt
{
    It it_;

    auto operator*() const
    {
        return std::tie(*it_, *std::next(it_));
    }

    auto operator++() -> auto& { ++it_; return *this; }
    auto operator!=(AdjancetRangeIt other) const { return it_ != other.it_; }
};

template <class It>
AdjancetRangeIt(It) -> AdjancetRangeIt<It>;

template <class It>
struct AdjacentRange
{
    It begin_, end_;

    template <class C>
    AdjacentRange(C& container)
        : begin_{std::begin(container)}, end_{std::end(container)}
    {}

    auto begin() const
    {
        return AdjancetRangeIt{begin_};
    }
    auto end() const
    {
        if (begin_ == end_)
            return AdjancetRangeIt{end_};
        else
            return AdjancetRangeIt{std::prev(end_)};
    }
};

template <class C>
AdjacentRange(C) -> AdjacentRange<typename C::iterator>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over two elements at the same time:

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4};

for (auto l = v.begin(), r = l + 1, e = v.end(); r != e; ++l, ++r)
    std::cout << '(' << *l << ", " << *r << ")\n";
```

Outputs:

> ```
> (1, 2)
> (2, 3)
> (3, 4)
> ```

Check it out in [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OPhxhkaT48giKYyn).

Comment: What happens with an empty container?

Comment: @6502 `r != e` evaluates to `false` and thus we don't enter into the loop .

Comment: Nope... in an empty container `l` is equal to `begin()` that is also equal to `e`; `r` instead is computed as `l+1`, i.e. `begin()+1` i.e. `end()+1`... thus...

Comment: @6502 you're right, `r != e` [doesn't evaluates to `false`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4ROQlxNLRQEnLPi3), neither enters the loop idk why. Regardless, the fix is pretty simple: as the other answers are doing, just check for emptyness.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with a `std::vector` this is a case in which using iterators is nonsense... an easy way using indexes would be

```
for (int i=0,n=numbers.size(); i<n-1; i++) {
    std::cout << '(' << numbers[i] << ", " << numbers[i+1] << ")\n";
}
```

Of course it CAN be done with iterators, but it's going to suck.

Answer (score 0):

In the upcoming C++23, you will be able to use views::slide(2) and views::adjacent(2). slide() produces a range of ranges, whereas adjacent() produces a range of tuples.
Example:

```
vector<int> ints = {1, 2, 3, 4};
auto rg = ints | views::adjacent(2);
/*{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}*/

auto [value1, value2] = (ints | views::adjacent(2))[0];
//value1=1
//value2=2
```