# traverse std::list , holding 2 last values

Tags: c++, list

I need to traverse the `std::list` holding 2 last values,i.e if my list is `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

```
iteration1 : v1 = 1, v2 = 2
iteration2 : v1 = 2, v2 = 3
iteration3 : v1 = 3, v2 = 4
iteration4 : v1 = 4, v2 = 5
iteration5 : v1 = 5, v2 = 6
```

I tried to

```
auto next = _contour.begin();
auto prev = next;

while( next != _contour.end())
{
    prev = next;
    next++;
}
```

But it doesn't work good - there is a problem at the end of traverse. In the last iteration `next` is pointing outside the list.

How can I do this correctly with good performance I don't want at each iteration check `next`?

Comment: I think the code is correct. You did check for `next!= _contour.end()`, so it should not exceed that.

Comment: I guess the real job is done after `next++` line, and there `next` can be equal to `.end()`.

Comment: The code in the question is definitely not correct. Wherever OP puts the actual loop body, it will not do the right thing.

Comment: You can't not check at every iteration, since the list might end at every iteration. You can unroll the loop for a little added performance, but the code you have is the standard.

Comment: @cdhowie ... that's right; but the op didn't show where the body is.

Comment: i think it can be solved using one more iterator

Comment: @user202729 It doesn't matter where the body is.

Comment: Very similar: [Get adjacent pairs of elements from vector via iterator in c++ - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55508811/get-adjacent-pairs-of-elements-from-vector-via-iterator-in-c) ; [c++ - for_each that gives two (or n) adjacent elements - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927563/for-each-that-gives-two-or-n-adjacent-elements)

Comment: How about https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8Kjren

Comment: @Ayxan, `std::prev` is not that cheap on a list.

Comment: @Evg how about this https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sqzPeM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as you've hinted at, is that you check if `next != _contour.end()` before incrementing it, and after incrementing it you cannot be certain that it's not equal to the end iterator.

To solve this problem, switch around the logic in your loop such that you test the new value of `next` before each iteration.

For example:

```
auto current = _contour.begin();
// Make sure the list isn't empty before we go charging ahead.
if (current != _contour.end()) {
    decltype(current) prev;

    while ((prev = current), (++current != _contour.end())) {
        std::cout << "v1:" << *prev << " v2:" << *current << std::endl;
    }
}
```

([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11545668bc0814be))

Comment: probably could move "current" into  `if()`  statement too

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Not without a redundant test, unless I'm misunderstanding what you're saying. To my knowledge, you can't declare a variable and test its initial value in the same conditional expression.

Comment: In C++17, `if (int i = 1; i != 0) {...}`.

Comment: ^ Except people not always can read that comma and semicolon "magic"

Comment: @Evg Ah, I was not aware of this new syntax. I'll just say that my answer is for C++11 or newer. (I don't like assuming that everyone has access to a C++17 implementation just yet.)

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should have increment and check condition swapped around  to not go out of  bounds. It can be done in several ways, using  various loops, e.g.

```
   auto  next = _contour.begin();
   auto prev = next;

   if( !_contour.empty())
     while( ++next != _contour.end())
     {
        //std::cout << *prev << ":" << *next << std::endl;
        prev = next;
     }
```

Or one-liner `for`:

```
  if( !_contour.empty())
     for(auto next = _contour.begin(), prev = next; ++next != _contour.end(); prev = next )
     {    
         //std::cout << *prev << ":" << *next << std::endl;
     }
```

Comment: Note: invokes undefined behavior if the list is empty.